# Sum Values from a Column for unique values in a different column (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an insurance customer dataset where the same user will appear multiple times. I want to sum up a column based on unique IDs in another. For example:

```
(column A (user_id), column B (total_paid))
(1, 5)
(2,10)
(3,15)
(4,20)
(5,10)
(5,10)
(5,10)
(6,12)
(6,12)
(6,12)

Total_paid = 72
```

Want to do this in Google Sheets for now before moving it over into native SQL. Thinking sumifs + countuniques, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:B; "select A,sum(B) where A is not null group by A label sum(B)''")
```

Comment: "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data" in the cell where the formula is. How do I fix this? @player0

Comment: @DarShavit this formula needs two empty columns to "roll out" the output